# mysql insert character in 2 position

Tags: mysql, insert

How do I insert a character to string in mysql in 2 positions? 
I have a string **'25022015'**, and I want insert '/' so that the result is **'25/02/2015'**. I tried `INSERT('25022015', 3, 0, '/')` and `INSERT('25022015', 6, 0,'/')`, but i got an error. Please help me

Comment: Should we be bold enough to ask how you use date columns

Comment: what is the error you got? please edit your question

Comment: I got error    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line1"

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
update table 
set column = concat(substring(column,1,2), '/',substring(column,3,2),'/',substring(column,5,4));
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b0d2/1/0